# Adding provisioning profiles without Apple's account

Tags: ios, xcode5, provisioning-profile

Im having troubles to generate IPA's from a project. I have the Certificate in my keychain but now i cant add the provisioning profile.

I read that in Xcode 5 this is handled by the Xcode, so you have to add an Apple developers account.

Is there any way to skip this step? I have the provisioning profile downloaded.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening provisioning profile with Xcode will copy it to appropriate folder, so you can select it from project settings. Xcode will check `/Users/youruser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` folder and you can also move you provisioning file there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Apple developer account to get provisioning profiles. When you got one go to Preferences -> Accounts -> Click on the + button.

Comment: yes, I know, but is there any way to skip this step?

Comment: @oPi I don't think so.